# mpdf errors using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, pdf

I downloaded mpdf and got it working locally with no issues.

I then began to attempt to integrate with my opencart code. But now when I try and run it using AJAX I get many errors. I tried turning off error reporting but then in my AJAX response , instead of getting all the errors I just get nothing, even though it should be at least finishing out the first function (ie sending back the json response).

EDIT: ok, I realised its still successfully generating the pdf, so my main issue now is getting the ajax to continue working. Currently if I put `error_reporting(0);` just inside the cssmgr class nothing happens, but the ajax fails, and when I put it at the top of the mpdf.php I still get the errors.

My PHP

```
public function get_html() {

    $childs_name = $this->request->post['childs_name'];      
    $childs_image = $this->request->post['childs_image'];    

    $this->CreatePdfFromImage($childs_name,$childs_image);

    $json = array();    

    $json['childs_name'] = $childs_name;
    $json['childs_image'] = $childs_image;

    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));



 }
 public function CreatePdfFromImage($childs_name, $childs_image) {

    include('convert-to-pdf/mpdf.php');
    $mpdf=new mPDF();

    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<html><body><div class="hello">Hello</div></body></html>');


    $mpdf->Output('test.pdf','F');


 }
```

And the errors...

```
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: BODY in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/classes/cssmgr.php</b> on line <b>973</b>

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: BODY>>ID>> in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/classes/cssmgr.php</b> on line <b>1018</b>

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined offset: -1 in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/classes/cssmgr.php</b> on line <b>1157</b>

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: DIV in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/classes/cssmgr.php</b> on line <b>973</b>

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: CLASS>>HELLO in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/classes/cssmgr.php</b> on line <b>976</b>

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: DIV>>CLASS>>HELLO in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/classes/cssmgr.php</b> on line <b>1014</b>

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: DIV>>ID>> in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/classes/cssmgr.php</b> on line <b>1018</b>

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: DIV in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/classes/cssmgr.php</b> on line <b>973</b>

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: CLASS>>HELLO in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/classes/cssmgr.php</b> on line <b>976</b>

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: DIV>>CLASS>>HELLO in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/classes/cssmgr.php</b> on line <b>1014</b>

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: DIV>>ID>> in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/classes/cssmgr.php</b> on line <b>1018</b>

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: outline-s in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/mpdf.php</b> on line <b>3893</b>

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: mPDF::$hasOC in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/mpdf.php</b> on line <b>27550</b>

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: mPDF::$hasOC in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/mpdf.php</b> on line <b>27653</b>

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined property: mPDF::$hasOC in <b>mysite/catalog/controller/pdfengine/convert-to-pdf/mpdf.php</b> on line <b>9177</b>
```